# Not able to connect openvpn ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, openvpn, google-authenticator, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to connect to openvpn with google authenticator enabled but it is showing the issue

> AUTH_FAILED,Google Authenticator Code must be a number

However I am able to connect it via web.

Please help me and thanks in advance

Comment: Think this is more a Server Fault question

Comment: Server Fault is a different StackExchange site (http://serverfault.com/) and I would agree with @CesarBielich that you will probably find better help over there. Furthermore, there probably isn't enough information in this question for it to be answered. Good luck on the 16.04 upgrade! I haven't pulled the trigger yet on my boxes. :/

Comment: I was able to connect once again after installing [openvpn 2.3.10 from source](https://openvpn.net/index.php/download/community-downloads.html) (ensuring to [verify its integrity](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/sig.html)). The most obvious difference was that the ubuntu provided package was trying to use `*` to mask the username, password and TOTP code, whereas the purely open source code used the normal password reading behavior (no asterisks, just entirely blank).

Comment: @PrameshGautam please link to your server-fault question, if you have opened one there, in case there is a much better answer then users will be able to find that question from this one

Answer (score 25):

This looks like an encoding issue. I was facing this after a dist upgrade to Ubuntu Xenial and solved this by simply changing the verbosity level.
Find your configuration file **(Usually *.ovpn)**, find the line which says `verb 3` and change it to `verb 4`. That makes it work.

If you can't find your ovpn file, try running a `grep -nar "verb 3"` on the root directory. That should help you find the file.

For example: `sudo openvpn --config client.ovpn --script-security 2` 
As in my case configuration file is `client.ovpn`

Comment: after I got this fixed by doing this I started another error after the update "resolvconf  Command not recognized"  I got that fixed by downloading the latest version of resolvconf from here: http://roy.marples.name/downloads/openresolv/  (openresolv-3.8.1)

Comment: https://ramzavil.wordpress.com/2016/07/25/how-to-fix-openvpn-not-working-in-ubuntu-16-04/ this helped me

Comment: How should verbosity affect the way input is taken? I mean, it works, but why?

Comment: But yes, It works

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue after installing openvpn from source
https://ramzavil.wordpress.com/2016/07/25/how-to-fix-openvpn-not-working-in-ubuntu-16-04/ tutorial over here

Comment: This worked for me as well.  The version installed by Ubuntu was 2.3.10-1ubuntu2.  The version that worked when installed from source was 2.3.14.